# Why can't I drop vertex properties?

Tags: gremlin, janusgraph

I can't drop any properties, they're just stubbornly remaining. What am I doing wrong?

```
gremlin> g.V(28712).valueMap()
==>{entity_id=[256a631b-3c19-49b7-84f3-01911d66c744], prop=[0]}

gremlin> g.V().properties('prop').drop()
gremlin> g.V(28712).valueMap()
==>{entity_id=[256a631b-3c19-49b7-84f3-01911d66c744], prop=[0]}

gremlin> g.V().properties('prop').drop().iterate()
gremlin> g.V(28712).valueMap()
==>{entity_id=[256a631b-3c19-49b7-84f3-01911d66c744], prop=[0]}

gremlin> g.V(28712).properties('prop').drop()
gremlin> g.V(28712).valueMap()
==>{entity_id=[256a631b-3c19-49b7-84f3-01911d66c744], prop=[0]}

gremlin> g.V(28712).properties('prop').drop().iterate()
gremlin> g.V(28712).valueMap()
==>{entity_id=[256a631b-3c19-49b7-84f3-01911d66c744], prop=[0]}
```

What's doubly strange is that it seems to show the drop was successful (there appears to be no vertices with the property `prop`), but calling `valueMap` on a specific vertex shows otherwise.

```
gremlin> g.V().properties('prop').drop()
gremlin> g.V().has('prop').count()
==>0
gremlin> g.V().has('prop', 0).count()
==>0
gremlin> g.V(28712).valueMap()
==>{entity_id=[256a631b-3c19-49b7-84f3-01911d66c744], prop=[0]}
```

Comment: What database are you using?  
When I try this in TinkerGraph I am not seeing an issue:  

gremlin> g.addV('Test').property('prop', 0).addV('Test').property('prop', 1)
==>v[44]
gremlin> g.V().valueMap()
==>[prop:[0]]
==>[prop:[1]]
gremlin> g.V().properties('prop').drop().iterate()
gremlin> g.V().valueMap()
==>[]
==>[]

Comment: Sorry - JanusGraph

Comment: Are you committing the transaction with graph.tx().commit() ?

Comment: That may not explain completely what you are seeing but at some point the TX will need to be committed. I did do a quick test with the 'inmemory' back end and could not reproduce what you are seeing. Which store do you have behind JanusGraph?

Comment: commit is missing